# How to play audio in flutter by precaching a list of audio asset files, using AudioPlayers 4.1.0 package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I'm doing flutter course bootcamp of 2020. So the version of some dart packages have changed.
I just want to play audio from a list precached.

In 2020, the AudioCache Class had the **play** method that was creating a new instance of AudioPlayer Class when we called it. But now, the AudioCache Class doesn't have that method anymore.And i don't know how to bind it (AudioCache and AudioPlayer Classes).